# Is it safe to delete a Veracrypt container, empty, never mounted?

Tags: veracrypt

Something weird happened with my computer as I was trying to work on the keyfiles and now I can't mount it the volume. I would like to just delete it but I wanted to make absolutely sure that it wouldn't do something weird to my computer if I did. Any help would be greatly appreciated, it's going to irk me until I can get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe. Just the same as deleting  file.